# ionic firebase get specific items from table

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

i want to get some specific items from firebase database

this is my firebase database

```
{
  "Militaire" : {
  "arabe" : "المتحف العسكري الوطني",
  "img" : "/Images/Musée-militaire.jpg",
  "name" : "Musée militaire national (Tunisie)",
  "tel" : "+21670 604 018"
 },
 "bardo" : {
     "arabe" : "المتحف الوطني بباردو
     "img" : "/Images/Le_musee_national_du_Bardo_78987.jpg",
     "name" : "Musée national du Bardo (Tunisie)",
     "tel" : "+21671513650"
       },
 "mareth" : {
     "arabe" : "المتحف العسكري لخط مـارث",
     "img" : "/Images/Musée-militaire.jpg",
     "name" : "Musée Militaire de la Ligne Mareth",
     "tel" : "+216 75 306 433"
     }
    }
```

i have the "name" from string variable and i want to display the arabic name from it.

Comment: my table name is museums i forgot to mention it

Comment: The only way you can do it is to do search filter like where result.name==name then get result as mareth and you put result.arabe

Comment: What problem do you have implementing this use-case? What code did you write, and which line in that code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i have this params from another page  `   this.names=this.navParams.get('name');   ` and i want get the museum with this name

Comment: i have this params from another page                                                                                    `this.names=this.navParams.get('name')`                                                                      and i want get the museum with this name                                                                                         this is my code to get all museums                                                                                               @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Don't provide the info in comments please. There's an edit link under your question, so that you can update it. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).